# Hofstadter Female and Male sequences in SML

Tags: sequence, sml, smlnj, ml, sequences

This is my first SML program. I am trying to write a function that returns the first number to the nth number of Hofstadter's Female or Male sequence in list form. What I have so far is:

```
val m = fn (n) => if n = 0 then 1 :: [] else m f (n - 1);
val f = fn (n) => if n = 0 then 0 :: [] else f m (n - 1);
```

You can learn about the sequence here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hofstadter_sequence#Hofstadter_Female_and_Male_sequences

The error that I am getting is:

```
[opening sequence.sml]
sequence.sml:1.49 Error: unbound variable or constructor: f
sequence.sml:1.47-1.58 Error: operator is not a function [tycon mismatch]
  operator: int list
  in expression:
    (m <errorvar>) (n - 1)
val it = () : unit
```

How can I correct this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up taking this approach:

```
fun
    m (n) = if n = 0 then 0 else n - (f (m (n - 1)))
and
    f (n) = if n = 0 then 1 else n - (m (f (n - 1)));
val seq = fn n => List.tabulate((n), f);
```

It is quite slow. If anybody has a faster version, then I'd love to see it.

Answer (score 1):

Although you have already fixed them, there were two problems with your original approach:

1. Function application is left-associative in SML so `m f (n - 1)` was being interpreted as `(m f) (n - 1)`, not the desired `m (f (n - 1))`. You can fix this by explicitly specifying the bracketing `m (f (n - 1))`.
2. To be able to call `f` from `m` *and* `m` from `f`, you need to use the keyword `fun` instead of `val` on the first declaration (to make the function recursive), and the keyword `and` instead of `fun` or `val` on the second declaration (to make the function mutually recursive with the first function). This would look like

   ```
   fun f n = ... (* I can call f or m from here! *)
   and m n = ... (* I can call f or m from here! *)
   ```

To make it faster, you can memoize! The trick is to make `f` and `m` take as arguments memoized versions of themselves.

```
(* Convenience function: Update arr[i] to x, and return x. *)
fun updateAndReturn arr i x = (Array.update (arr, i, SOME x); x)

(*
 * Look up result of f i in table; if it's not found, calculate f i and
 * store in the table. The token is used so that deeper recursive calls
 * to f can also try to store in the table.
 *)
fun memo table f token i =
  case Array.sub (table, i)
    of NONE => updateAndReturn table i (f token i)
     | SOME x => x

(*
 * Given f, g, and n : int, returns a tuple (f', g') where f' and g' are memoized
 * versions of f and g, respectively. f' and g' are defined only on the domain
 * [0, n).
 *)
fun memoizeMutual (f, g) n =
  let
    val fTable = Array.array (n, NONE)
    val gTable = Array.array (n, NONE)
    fun fMemo i = memo fTable f (fMemo, gMemo) i
    and gMemo i = memo gTable g (gMemo, fMemo) i
  in
    (fMemo, gMemo)
  end

fun female _ 0 = 1
  | female (f, m) n = n - m (f (n - 1))

fun male _ 0 = 0
  | male (m, f) n = n - f (m (n - 1))

fun hofstadter upTo =
  let
    val (male', female') = memoizeMutual (male, female) upTo
  in
    (List.tabulate (upTo, male'), List.tabulate (upTo, female'))
  end
```

I renamed `f` and `m` to `female` and `male`. The memoized `fMemo` and `gMemo` are threaded through `female` and `male` by `memoizeMutual`. Interestingly, if we call `male'`, then results for *both* `male'` and `female'` are memoized.

To confirm it's indeed faster, try evaluating `hofstadter 10000`. It's much faster than the forever that your version would take.

As a final note, the only recursive functions are `fMemo` and `gMemo`. Every other function I wrote could be written as an anonymous function (`val memoizeMutual = fn ...`, `val female = fn ...`, etc.), but I chose not to do so because the syntax for writing recursive functions is much more compact in SML.

To generalize this, you could replace the array version of memoizing with something like a hash table. Then we wouldn't have to specify the size of the memoization up front.

Comment: Thank you very much for posting and explaining your solution. 'Memoization' is a new process for me. I look forward to implementing it in the future. Thank you for your time.